# How to position a div dynamically below another?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to use jQuery to detect the position of a div (`#olddiv`), so I can use that position to place another div (`#newdiv`) exactly below it. The right borders of the 2 divs are aligned (right border).

I'm trying to get the `#olddiv` bottom and right locations to use them as the `#newdiv` top and right borders. I've used this code, but it's not working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var right = $('#olddiv').position().right;
var top = $('#olddiv').position().bottom;
$('#newdiv').css('top', right);
$('#newdiv').css('right', top);
```

Also, I'm not sure if `position` is what I need. I think this can be done with `position` or `offset`, but I'm not sure:

```
$('#ID').position().left
$('#ID').offset().left
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've used offset() to position elements dynamically. Try this:

```
var offset = $('#olddiv').offset();
var height = $('#olddiv').height();
var width = $('#olddiv').width();
var top = offset.top + height + "px";
var right = offset.left + width + "px";

$('#ID').css( {
    'position': 'absolute',
    'right': right,
    'top': top
});
```

also don't forget to bind this to the `window.onresize` event if you need it to scale when the user resizes the window.

**UPDATE:** another thought - does this have to be positioned absolutely? Why not just insert the div after the other in the DOM?

```
$('#olddiv').after($('#ID').html());
```

then just make sure they are the same width.

Comment: Thanks great answer. It had to be absolute because I'm planning for it to superimpose other divs. That's why the regular after didn't work. Your top solution worked though. Thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

There is a pretty cool [plugin](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Position) getting developed by the jQuery UI team that helps with [position](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Position).

Lets you do something like this:

```
$(".menu").position({ my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: ".menubutton" });
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple. To keep this up-to-date, when using the plugin and wanting to make use of the `collision` attribute there seems to be an issue in the current combination of jQuery 1.9.x with jQueryUI 1.9.x whereby the `flip` setting of the `collision` attribute is not working as expected. The last working combo seems to be jQuery 1.7.2 with jQueryUI 1.8.20. The jQueryUI bug tracker for it is: [**http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8710**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8710)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I've used that in a website I made, to display a div in a certain position, always relative to another div and always relative to the dimensions of the browser window (even when you stretch it manually).

Here's the code:

```
// function to place the div
var newdiv = function () {
   var o = $('#olddiv').offset();
   var h = $('#olddiv').height();
   var w = $('#olddiv').width();
   $('#newdiv').css({'top': o.top,
                     'left': o.left,
                     'width': w,
                     'height': h       
   }).show();
}

// listen the window changes and correct the newdiv position
$(window).resize(function(){ newdiv(); });

// display the newdiv after DOM is loaded, or whenever you want
newdiv();
```

Note that you may need to add another vars to the css above, like margin, padding, etc, in order to get the right position, or even add manually values to top and left, in case the new div isn't exactly like the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo, does fixing:

```
'top', right
'right', top
```

help at all?

The divs need to be positioned absolutely or relatively in order for this code to work as well.