# Fix div position and load mouse over content over another div using z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, mouseover

My data is correctly alerting the data on `mouseover` over the div, however i m still struggling with my CSS weakness. I need to display the data over the `rightsideblock` div using `z-index` property on mouseover instead of alerting. I created a class `mydatatoshow` to hold the data with rhe display set to none but i am not able to configure it correctly. Help me with this as i googled a lot. Kindly suggest some links that may be helpful for developers for fixing css issues.

**EDIT**
one more problem im facing with my event is that on adding this code --var mydata = $(this).text(); $('.mydatatoshow').append(mydata); it adds data corectly to the div but i want that on mouse out the data also vanishes

My CSS --

```
<style type="text/css">
.container{width:999px;}
.leftsideblock{float:left; border:1px solid green;width:674px;}
.rightsideblock{border:5px solid blue;}
</style>
```

My Body Content --

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="leftsideblock">
    <div class="mydivdata">
<table width="650" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="193" valign="top">Monday 07 July 2012</td>
<td width="424">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

    <div class="mydivdata">
<table width="650" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="193" valign="top">Friday 06 July 2012 8:00AM</td>
<td width="424">
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
    </div>


    <div class="mydatatoshow" style="display:none;">
    </div>

    <div class="rightsideblock">
    <p>
    This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right    sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.
    </p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

My JS--

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mydivdata').mouseover(function(){
var mydata = $(this).text();
alert(mydata);
});
});
</script>
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JsnDc/

Comment: you can change the z-index value of your div using jquery

Comment: @MohammadAdil yup bro but im totally handicap with css part..dont know how to set div "mydatatoshow" over "rightsideblock" using z-index thats why provided the whole code and efforts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Solution --

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .container{width:999px;}
    .leftsideblock{float:left; border:1px solid green;width:674px;}
    .rightsideblock{border:5px solid blue;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mydivdata').mouseover(function(){
    $('.mydatatoshow').css('z-index', '9999');
    $('.mydatatoshow').show();
    //     document.getElementById('to_hide').style.display='none';
    var mydata = $(this).text();
    $('.mydatatoshow').html(mydata);        
    });

    $('.mydivdata').mouseout(function(){
    $('.mydatatoshow').hide();
    //document.getElementById('to_hide').style.display='block';
    });


    });
    </script>

    <title>Test To Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <table>
        <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <div class="leftsideblock">
                <div class="mydivdata">
                    <table width="650" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="193" valign="top">Monday 07 July 2012</td>
                            <td width="424">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="mydivdata">
                    <table width="650" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="90" valign="top" rowspan="2" class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="193" valign="top">Friday 06 July 2012 8:00AM</td>
                        <td width="424">
                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="rightsideblock" style="top: 0;position: absolute;width: 300px;float: right;">
                <p style="z-index:-1">
                    This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right    sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.This is right sidebar data.
                </p>

            <div class="mydatatoshow" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999; float: right; position: absolute; display: none; ">



                        &nbsp;
                        Friday 06 July 2012 8:00AM

                            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.




                </div></div>

            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>




    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.mydivdata').mouseover(function(){
        $('.mydatatoshow').css('z-index', '9999');
    });
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850732/how-might-i-use-jquery-to-position-one-div-dynamically-below-another) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850732/how-might-i-use-jquery-to-position-one-div-dynamically-below-another) to position your div correctly.

Comment: @MohammadAli one more problem im facing with my event is that on adding this code --var mydata = $(this).text();
    $('.mydatatoshow').append(mydata); it adds data corectly to the div but i want that on moue out the data also vanishes

Comment: @MohammadAli yes but what is the reverse of append?? Now this is my code  but not working on mouse out --  $(document).ready(function(){

$('.mydivdata').mouseover(function(){
        //$('.mydatatoshow').css('z-index', '9999');
  var mydata = $(this).text();
  $('.mydatatoshow').append(mydata);
  
  $('.mydivdata').mouseout(function(){
  $('.mydatatoshow').remove(mydata);
  });
  
    });



});

Comment: what you can do here is ..just take a copy of text that you have inside your `mydatatoshow` before appending to it.. and on mouseout just put your backed up text back into `mydatatoshow`

Comment: @MohammadAli can u please set a jsfiddle for that with less content ..just to grasp the logic :)